# How to program the buttons beside my unordered list elements to delete its associate list element when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to make a simple to-do list app and would like the buttons beside each list element to have the effect of deleting their respective element when clicked. My code so far is the following:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>To-Do List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>To-Do List</h1>
        <input type="text" id="input"/>
        <input type="button" value="Add Note" id="add"/>
        <ul id="list"></ul>
    <script charset="utf-8">
        document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
        var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var li = "<li>" + text + "<button>Delete</button></li>";
        document.getElementById("list").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
        document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clear the value
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a `click` listener to the delete buttons and remove their parent (`li`) on click as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var li = "<li>" + text + "<button onclick='deleteItem(this)'>Delete</button></li>";
    document.getElementById("list").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', li);
    document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clear the value
}

function deleteItem(btn){
    btn.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(btn.parentNode)
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To-Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To-Do List</h1>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <input type="button" value="Add Note" id="add"/>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```